# I need a logic code to create the below json structure dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

```
{
"2016-01-02": { command: 5, url: "" },
"2015-05-26": { command: 1, url: "" },
"2015-05-03": { command: 2, url: "" },
}
```

I need a logic code to create the json structure dynamicaly.

I cerated the JSON with the below code,it is working fine but i need it as a list like the above json structure.

```
$.each(databaseData, function (ind, val) { 
var dateFormated = val.date; //This data comming from database
var jsonFormatedDate = dateFormated;
jsonFormatedData[jsonFormatedDate] = { "command": val.command, "url":   val.url      }
console.log(jsonFormatedData)
});
```

OUTPUT

```
{
"2016-01-02": { command: 5, url: "" }
}
```

Comment: i think it is fine, try adding more items to `jsonFormatedData`

Answer (score 3):

You probably wanted to keep the object *outside* the loop

```
var jsonFormatedDate = {};

$.each(databaseData, function (ind, val) { 
    jsonFormatedData[val.date] = { command: val.command, url: val.url};
});

console.log(jsonFormatedDate)
```